# How to perform an integration test with the Opentok API?

Tags: selenium, testing, cucumber, capybara, integration-testing

We're using the OpenTok API for P2P video and would like to automate testing - ideally using capybara/cucumber.

Is there a command to observe a publisher/subscriber div to see if its publishing/receiving video?

Comment: please add the referred div to question, using selenium you can get attributes of html elements and verify whether it is publishing or receiving video.

Comment: Couldn't you just answer using a sample ID? Lets just say the publisher div in this case has an ID of 'publisher'.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **getAttribute** method to get the Id of html element as explained below:

```
// use any locator to find the element you are targeting, for e.g. xpath 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.XPath("Your Element Xpath"));
String value = element.getAttribute("id");

if (value.equals("publisher")){
    // actions to be done when the status is publisher
} else if(value.equals("subscriber")) {
    // actions to be done when the status is subscriber
} else {
    // unknown state
}
```

Comment: The question relates to discovering if a div is sending/receiving video. I have no problem with capturing the div in the first place.

Comment: selenium is not equipped if to see if video is streaming/publishing/subscribing. generally these type tests will be done based on the html attributes or javascript values set by the application and assert on those conditions, which I have compiled as an answer. I never used OpenTok, but you may get help seeing the test repo https://github.com/aullman/opentok-test-scripts